# How i will get multiple data from shared preference?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have saved multiple data using shared preference. I want to read multiple data from shared preference. I have tried but can not success. I can read one data but unable to read multiple data.Thanks.

```
//Save multiple data  

private static int incrementedValue = 0;
saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SharedPreferences faves = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    String id  = idEditText.getText().toString();
    String name  = nameEditText.getText().toString();

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = faves.edit();
    editor.putString("favourite" + incrementedValue, id + "::" + name + ",");
    editor.commit();

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
    incrementedValue++;
   }
})
```

Here is read data from shared preference code.

```
//Show multiple data

showBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SharedPreferences faves = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
            String id = faves.getString("favourite", "");
            String name = faves.getString("favourite","");

           textShow.setText(id+" "+name);

           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Show!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Whenever you store the value in preference you are setting incremented value.But you are getting the value with "favourite" only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made the key as `"favourite" + incrementedValue` and accessing the value with the key `"favourite"` which are not the same, and it looks like you have saved both the values id and name in a single String which is again inappropriate, so change your code like this,

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = faves.edit();
editor.putString("favourite id" + incrementedValue, id);
editor.putString("favourite name" + incrementedValue, name);
editor.commit();
```

and access data like this,

```
SharedPreferences faves = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
String id = faves.getString("favourite id"+INCREMENT_VALUE_COUNT, "");
String name = faves.getString("favourite name"+INCREMENT_VALUE_COUNT,"");
```

You have to replace INCREMENT_VALUE_COUNT with the position number you want to get data of.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple data in SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = faves.edit();
editor.putString("id", id);
editor.putString("name", name);
editor.commit()
```

You could get the value by

```
String id = (faves.getString("id", "0"));
String name = (faves.getString("name", ""));
```

As Here you are adding value separated by :: and ,.
You should get

```
 String favourite = faves.getString("favourite", "");
```

And split favourite by `,` and get separated values and after that split by  `::`